# Display json response on ajax call via POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Im trying to display some data via JSON using ajax but for some reason when i submit the form im not getting any result, any suggestions?..

project_view.php

```
   <form id="formProjectsRepSearch" action="controller.php" method="post" onsubmit="searchFormProjectsRep();
            return false">
            <label>Project Name </label>
            <input name="terbusqueda" id="term" type="text">
            <button id="btnBuscar">Search</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="search" value="go">
  </form>
  <div id="ajaxProjectsRep">        
  </div>
```

controller.php

```
  if (isset($_POST["search"]) && $_POST["search"] == "go"){

      $name = $_POST['terbusqueda'];

      $project = new Project();
      $pro = $project->get_project($name);  
      $serv = $project->get_project_service_by_id($pro);

      echo json_encode($serv);       
}
require_once("../views/project_view.php");
```

JS

```
function searchFormProjectsRep() {
var $form = $('#formProjectsRepSearch');

$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    success: function (resp) {
        var resp_object = $.parseJSON(resp); 
        $("#ajaxProjectsRep").html(resp_object.service);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
}
```

Comment: get rid of `$.parseJSON(resp);`, it's already parsed. You should see an error in your console. Why are you including `project_view.php` after echoing json?

Comment: please post the console error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing JSON twice in your code.

When `$.ajax()` is used with `dataType: "json"`, jQuery automatically parse the response string, so in your case `resp` is alreay a Javascript object. Since `resp` is an object and `$.parseJSON()` expects a string, `resp_object` is null. Try using resp directly, it should work.

You can use `console.log(resp)` to see what's the actual result returned by your PHP script.

(Also, I see you are converting the response into an HTML element with `.html()`, in that case you could pass `dataType: "html"` to `$.ajax()` and `resp` would alreay be a jQuery node, but that's not the question here.)

Comment: Im checking the console and for some reason im only seeing that i get the json echo out from the php at the top [{"service":"Reparacion 60kVA","status":"2"},{"service":"Instalaciones 2+1","status":"1"},{"service":"Mantenimiento Gen","status":"4"}] and all the html below, which is weird. Also i tried doing $("#ajaxProjectsRep").append(resp.service); but nothing, same thing.

Comment: Does your `require_once("../views/project_view.php");` outputs HTML? If yes, then it's normal that the HTML is after the JSON response. You can't do both; The first echo outputs the JSON text you pasted, and then the project_view.php echoes some HTML. You'll have to remove the `echo json_encode` or make the view outputs in an object before encoding and echoing it. What does project_view.php do?

Comment: It outputs the html of the page as i showed above.. Im separating the code using MVC thats why im requiring project_view.php from the controller. Before this i was displaying the data using a simple foreach in project_view.php among the html but now im required to show the data using json

Comment: If you want the data in JSON format, you will have to make a completely different view that generates JSON instead of HTML. Or, if you intend to display the HTML directly, get rid of the first `echo json_encode(` so it outputs only HTML, then use `dataType: "html"` and `$("#ajaxProjectsRep").append(resp)`. I you need only HTML data, you don't need JSON at all.

Answer (score 0):

you encode your data into JSON form in php code now after ajax call u have to parse it to show onto your html element .below is code how to parse it . first show all data in object form  into your browser console and then it will display time_in value!

```js
var data = JSON.parse(responce);
console.log(data[0]); // wholeobject
time_in = console.log(data[0].time_in);//only one field
```